# Possible bug LaplaceTransform in Mathematica

Tags: integral-transforms

Let us consider in Mathematica 13.0 on Windows 10/Linux

```
LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s]
```

> `E^(-2 (2 + s))`

and then

```
 InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, x]
```

> `DiracDelta[-2 + x]/E^4`

I was learned that `DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2]` should be returned. Which command incorrectly works: the former or the latter? or both?

Addition. The same issue with

```
FourierTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s];
InverseFourierTransform[%, s, x]
```

> `DiracDelta[-2 + x]/E^4`

Addition 2.  The distributions $\delta(x−2)e^{-x^2}$ and $\delta(x−2)e^{−4 }$ are not the same since their derivatives differ.

Comment: It is the same. Look up what a Delta function means!

Comment: If: $$\delta (x-2)=\underset{e\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{| x-2| }{e}\right)}{2 e}$$ then Try: `Limit[LaplaceTransform[Exp[-Abs[x - 2]/e]/(2 e)* Exp[-x^2], x, s, 
  Assumptions -> e >= 0], e -> 0, Assumptions -> s > 0, 
 Direction -> -1]` gives: `E^(-2 (2 + s))`.Looks like is **NOT** a bug.

Comment: @MariuszIwan;uk: (i) In  $$ \delta (x-2)=\underset{e\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{| x-2| }{e}\right)}{2 e} $$  the limit is taken in the weak topology (e.g. see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) as a first reading) and current CASes do not hande it. (ii) `InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s],s,x]` must return `DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2]` if the transforms exist. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Fourier transform of distributions is a hard matter (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function)) which cannot be handled with bare hands.

Comment: So what do you think is the answer for LaplaceTransform? **Maple** gives the same answer as **Mathematica**.

Comment: @MariuszIwan;uk:  Laplace transform is closely connected to Fourier transform as [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) informs.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Can you ground your claim "It is the same", giving us details? TIA.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: How is `LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s]` defined? The integral $\int_0^\infty \delta(x-2)e^{-x^2-sx}\,dx$ makes no sense in math.

Comment: The LP is clearly correct. The inverse LP might be wrong, I don't know offhand. The fact that the input fails to round trip is a sign of trouble.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: You simply repeat your claim "The LP is clearly correct"="It is the same", not grounding it. The integral $\int_0^\infty \delta(x-2)e^{-x^2-sx}\,dx$ makes no sense in traditional math.

Comment: @DanielLichblau:  I'd like to elaborate my claim. The distributions $\delta(x-2)e^{=x^2}$ and $\delta(x-2)e^{-4}$ are not the same since their derivatives differ.

Comment: The Dirac delta function is a distribution, so when you compare two expressions involving delta functions, you need integration with a test function: $\int_{2-\epsilon}^{2+\epsilon} \delta(x-2) e^{-x^2} f(x) dx$ vs. $\int_{2-\epsilon}^{2+\epsilon} \delta(x-2) e^{-4} f(x) dx$. And they are the same in this sense.

Comment: @tueda: Can you give a reference in math literature to the definite integrals of distributions? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Well, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html or some pages on Wikipedia or some basic textbooks...

Comment: @user64494 I think you can pick up some reference (math textbook) from that page or Wikipedia, if you want.

Comment: @tueda: The Math World is not a math literature. This is a site of Wolfram Research, Inc. I will be waiting for a serious reply to my request.

Comment: @user64494 Then, is [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Delta-function) OK for you? I saw you linked to it for Generalized function and Laplace transform... That page seems to cite some Schwartz's paper and other math literature.

Comment: @tueda: Sorry, I don't find any definite integrals of distributions in this article of  Encyclopedia of Mathematics. I will be waiting for a serious reply to my request.

Comment: @user64494 As far as I understand, the first identity in the article of Encyclopedia of Mathematics is a more or less formal definition of the Dirac delta distribution, defined by integration with a sufficiently smooth test function $f$. If you need a more mathematically formal definition beyond that, then sorry, I have no ideas.

Comment: @tueda: I'd like to cite the conclusion of this article "Thus, the delta-function is not an ordinary function in the sense of the classical theory of functions, and is defined in the theory of generalized functions as a singular generalized function, i.e. as the continuous linear functional in the space of infinitely-differentiable functions f of compact support, assigning to f its value at zero". BTW, did you pay your attention to my statement "The distributions $\delta(x−2)e^{−x^2}$ and $\delta(x−2)e^{−4}$ are not the same since their derivatives differ"?

Comment: @user64494 If I am allowed to use the definition of the delta function in the article of Encyclopedia of Mathematics, then it is easy to prove the derivatives are also the same: $\int [\delta(x-2) e^{-x^2}]' f(x) = \int [\delta(x-2) e^{-4}]' f(x)$, by integration by parts.

Comment: @tueda: I repeat I don't know any successful definition of the definite integrals of distributions. Both [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) and W. Rudin, Functional analysis say nothing about it.

Comment: $\delta(x-2)e^{-x^2}=\delta'(x-2) e^{-x^2}+ \delta(x-2)e^{-x^2}(-2x)$ and $\delta(x-2)e^{-4}= \delta'(x-2)e^{-4}$.

Comment: In [the article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function#Differentiation.) $f\star\delta$ stands for convolution, not multiplcation.

Comment: See 6.13 in the book of W.Rudin.

Comment: Can the down-voter ground this down-vote? TIA.

Comment: Can the second down-vote be grounded? Do the down-votes fix the bug?

Comment: Well, I'm a second down-voter. To me, the Mathematica result makes perfect sense, since `Exp[-x^2` is the same as `Exp[-4]` at `x==2`, the only point that matters. In the usual practical uses of `DiracDelta` that's what your problem **means**: you're sampling an input at a single point, so the sample is the value of that input there, and no other point in the input can have any influence on the result. Build a circuit that implements your math and try it out!

Comment: @JohnDoty: I'd like to quote Encyclopedia of Mathematics :""The concept of a generalized function makes it possible to express in a mathematically-correct form such idealized concepts as the density of a material point, a point charge or a point dipole, the (space) density of a simple or double layer, the intensity of an instantaneous source, etc. On the other hand, the concept of a generalized function reflects the fact that in reality a physical quantity cannot be measured at a point; only its mean values over sufficiently small neighbourhoods of a given point can be measured. '."

Comment: Both `DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2]` and `DiracDelta[-2 + x]/E^4` have the same `LaplaceTransform` according to Mathematica, and if you do the integrals by hand for the definition of the `LaplaceTransform` you will see they are the same.

Comment: What does the Encyclopedia of Mathematics say about applying `DiracDelta` to the sort of problem Dirac invented it solve?

Comment: @JohnDoty: Encylclopedia of Mathematics says nothing about the command of Mathematica `DiracDelta`.

Comment: Give an example of a physical system that your problem attempts to model.

Comment: @JohnDoty: Your  request is aside to Mathematica and mathematics. Hope I am clear.

Comment: You quote your encyclopedia as stating the application of the delta function is physical situations. Therefore, if *Mathematica* gives a result consistent with such applications, it is doing its job. And if you don't understand this, you can hardly expect to understand the mathematics.

Comment: The definitive book here isn't your encyclopedia, but https://www.amazon.com/Fourier-Transform-Its-Applications/dp/0073039381

Comment: @JohnDoty: Let us end this discussion which is aside to the question.   If you have concrete mathematical arguments , please state these arguments. All the best.

Comment: Read Bracewell's book. You have not found a bug. It would only be a bug if it got the wrong answer for a practical problem. But it got the simplest right answer.

Comment: Perhaps the root of your confusion is that you expect the definite integral to preserve details of the generalized function you're integrating. But the integral of the delta function erases those details. That is, indeed, its purpose: to remove irrelevant details from physical problems.

Comment: I didn't look carefully enough. The inverse LP is giving a fine result. Voting to migrate this to math.SE since it is really a question about the underlying math. (People have explained the math in comments, but, well, sometimes that's how it is...)

Comment: Thee is a claim in the comments (I cannot seem to copy and paste directly) that the integral defining the LP makes no sense in this case. Why is that being claimed? Are we ignoring the theory of distributions entirely? Maybe this time the poster should actually ground some claims. Otherwise this is just a waste of time-- people respond with the background math and it gets ignored for reasons unstated.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I just gave this the fifth downvote. I will add that my downvotes are rare, maybe a 2-4 in any year and I think this might be my first one this year. But this post is exasperating. The Laplace transform, defined as an integral, seems just fine for this example. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

This really isn't that hard, so let's go through it step by step.  Look at the two expressions of interest here, the one you start with and the one Mathematica subsequently returns.

```
LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s]
(*  E^(-2*(s + 2))  *)
```

and

```
LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-4], x, s]
(*  E^(-2*(s + 2))  *)
```

Both expressions give the same `LaplaceTransform`  which means either of those expressions is correct for the `InverseLaplaceTransform` of $e^{-2 (s+2)}$.  That is not saying that the two expressions are the same value, but only that they have the same LaplaceTransform.  We can manually compute these LaplaceTransforms to show Mathematica is correct.

The `LaplaceTransform` if `f[x]` is given by

`Lt = Integrate[f[x]*Exp[(-s)*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]`

Define

```
f1[x_] = Exp[-x^2 - s x]

f2[x_] = Exp[-4 - s x]
```

The integrals giving the Laplace Transforms are therefore:

```
lt1 = Integrate[DiracDelta[x - 2]*f1[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(*  E^(-2*(s + 2))  *)

lt2 = Integrate[DiracDelta[x - 2]*f2[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(*  E^(-2*(s + 2))  *)
```

Both giving the same correct answers as before.  Mathematica appears to be using the standard DiracDelta integral

$\int_a^b \delta (x-c) f(x) \, dx=f(c)$

for `c` within the limits of `a` and `b`,and `0` otherwise.  Some of the math references you have posted include this formula.  In our case `c = 2` which is within `0` to Infinity and manually computing the integrals for lt1 and lt2 is as simple as evaluating

```
f1[2]
```

and

```
f2[2]
```

giving the same correct values as before.

Contrary to the many examples of DiracDelta integrals one finds on the Web, an infinite integral is not required.  The only place in the universe that `DiracDelta[x-2]` is non-zero is at `x = 2`.   Any integration limits that straddle `x = 2` will give the same integral value as infinite limits will.

Comment: +1 The beauty and simplicity of the dirac-delta-concept simply explained with expertise!

Answer (score 7):

Okay, let's totally forget about what `DiracDelta` means in common sense and just consider whether the phenomenon the OP observed with Mathematica 13.0 is a bug or not.

The inverse Laplace transform of the Laplace transofm of a function $g$, $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\mathcal{L}[g]]$ should be $g$, which is explained in the Wolfram's reference of [InverseLaplaceTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html) and indeed

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[g[t], t, s], s, t]
```

gives

```
g[t]
```

For the OP's expression $\delta(x-2) e^{-x^2}$, the above property doesn't hold and actually

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2] Exp[- x^2], x, s], s, x]
```

gives

```
DiracDelta[-2 + x] / E^4
```

which is not the original input and so this should be wrong; this is the main point of the OP's claim.

But the "Possible Issues" section of [LaplaceTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) states that

> Simplification can be required to get back the original form

So let's ask Mathematica whether these two expressions are the same (or at least whether Mathematica considers/defines they are equivalent to each other):

```
Simplify[DiracDelta[x - 2] Exp[- x^2] == DiracDelta[-2 + x] / E^4]
```

which gives

```
True
```

as expected based on common sense. And of course, Mathematica considers their derivatives are also the same (`Simplify` is not needed in this case):

```
D[DiracDelta[x - 2] Exp[- x^2], x] == D[DiracDelta[-2 + x] / E^4, x]
```

```
True
```

**Summary**: this is not a bug.

**Edit**: the OP complained that "as expected based on common sense" is not math, in the comment, but the above answer does not intend to show any background math; it is a logic trying to show Mathematica is indeed working consistently, with a bit of abstraction of the details of the definition/implementation of the delta function, the Laplace transform and its inverse, which I feel worth sharing. (And, logic and abstraction are what you need for doing math.)

Another thing I would like to clarify is: the OP does not seem to like Mathematica reduces

```
D[Exp[- x^2] DiracDelta[x - 2], x]
```

to

```
Derivative[1][DiracDelta][-2 + x] / E^4
```

but this makes perfect sense because (sorry, the below is the math the OP doesn't like)
$$
\int_{2-\epsilon_1}^{2+\epsilon_2} \left[ e^{-x^2} \delta(x-2) \right]' f(x) dx
=
\int_{2-\epsilon_1}^{2+\epsilon_2} e^{-4} \left[ \delta(x-2) \right]' f(x) dx
=
- e^{-4} f'(2),
$$
for a sufficiently smooth test function $f(x)$ with positive $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. Indeed, `Integrate` can perform the above integral. I must admit Mathematica works very well with the delta function than I thought it would be.

Comment: Sorry, as "expected based on common sense" is not math. Also `D[Exp[- x^2]*D[DiracDelta[x - 2] , x]` results in `Derivative[1][DiracDelta][-2 + x]/E^4`, but this contradicts formula (5) in section 6.15 of  W. Rudin, Functional Analysis, where $(uv)‘=u′v+uv′$ is clearly written. Up to this section,
$$(e^{-x^2}\delta(x−2))′=−2xe^{−x^2}\delta(x−2)+e^{−x^2}\delta(x−2)′.$$
Summary: this is not any answer to the question under consideration

Comment: The Leibniz product rule $(uv)' = u' v + u v'$ is for ordinary functions. The delta function is not an ordinary function, as you cited yesterday, so you can't use this rule naively. If you have questions in math, not in Mathematica, then asking in math.SE would give you more beneficial math arguments.

Comment: By the way, what I said (you can't use the Leibniz rule) was not accurate, but then you need to consider what the 2nd term $e^{-x^2} [\delta(x-2)]'$ means, to obtain the final result $e^{-4} [\delta(x-2)]'$.

Comment: @user64494 The behavior of `Derivative` here may perhaps be considered a bug. However, the fact that `LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-x^2], x, s]` and  `LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x - 2]*Exp[-4], x, s]` yield equivalent expressions is a trivial consequence of the fundamental integral definition of the δ function along with the definition of the Laplace transform. And then, of course, the fact that their inverse Laplace transforms are equivalent is also trivial. So, perhaps you need to formulate a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown to me reason I cannot comment @BillWatts post ("Too long by 224 characters") so I present my comment as an answer.

You wrote "Mathematica appears to be using the standard DiracDelta integral
$\int_a^b \delta (x-c) f(x) \, dx=f(c)$" as your main argument. That was discussed
at the forum many times. I recall that  [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function)
and W. Rudin, Functional analysis say nothing about the definition of the definite integrals of distributions as well the references there (The unsuccessful attempt to give that definition was made in P. Antosik, J. Mikusiński, R. Sikorski, "Theory of distributions. The sequential approach" , Elsevier (1973) ).
This integral simply makes no sense in math. You also wrote "Some of the math references you have posted include this formula ". Can you
give exact references? TIA. My conclusion is your post does not answer the question at all.

Comment: That integral, with limits replaced by -/+infinity, is one of the definitions of the Dirac delta functional (distribution).

Comment: Complaining that functional analysis says nothing about the definite integral of the Dirac δ function is similar to complaining that Euclidean geometry says nothing about calculus. Dirac **defined** his δ function in terms of definite integrals, and successfully applied it to solve physics problems. Generations of physicists and engineers have followed that path. That it doesn't fit your parochial conception of how math should work is of no concern to those of us who use Dirac δ. Your concern is similar to that of the mathematicians who denied that Newton and Fourier's math was proper.

Comment: Look at the very first formula of https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Delta-function.

Comment: If you don't like that formula I don't see how anyone can help you.  You certainly can't ask Mathematica to return an integral you will accept.  Maybe the Math StackExchange is the place you need to go for delta-function questions.